# Is it possible to get graphs of the stats for moderator candidates?

Tags: feature-request, election

Considering that users will use the candidates past site activity as a way to judge them.

- What if a candidate was only active 2 years ago, but then his activity started to decline?
- What if he was only active few months before the election?
- What if his activity is only limited to couple of months in each year?

I think it would be nice to see their activity on a graph with relation to time, so we know ***when*** he was active.

Comment: +1. Many graphs. One for each action type(votes/flags/edits/etc). With 25 candidates, it's hard to get an in-depth look at them all. Graphs could help me narrow it down to a few that interest me, and I could go deeper on those.

Comment: Considering that to get the whole picture you should look at *what* they're doing and *how*, not just how much, I'm not sure graphs would be very helpful. At least, not in a way that you wouldn't get by just looking at a candidate's activity and timestamps.

Comment: Graphs for what? Just reputation, or also flags and review queue activity? All of the above?

Comment: @AnnaLear I understand what you mean, 'what' they were doing is a factor of course, but in my opinion, still the 'when' is important to know, the time distribution could be helpful. -- from the comments on the candidate 'Kolink' , two days ago he had 89 helpful flags, now he has 112, so I think WHEN did he get those 89 helpful flags could be really helpful in deciding whether to vote for him or not (it could be all done in the last month).

Comment: @DavidRobinson I suppose all the data that are displayed as numbers only.

Comment: @AnnaLear A candidate's activity and timestamps are fine if you only have a couple candidates. I just clicked on the "activity" tab for the [most recent candidate](http://stackoverflow.com/users/122607/lord-torgamus?tab=activity&sort=all). It's 157 pages long. Even if I wanted to look at "just" revisions, it's 60 pages. For one category of one candidate. I just want something to help me narrow it down to a few I want to look at. Infographics are a good way to get a lot of material digested in short order.